# download image from google cloud storage and send it in a request fails

Tags: node.js, arrays, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I am trying to write a code to first download a dicom image from google cloud storage in python and send it over to a nodejs server in a post request. here is the code snippet

```
from google.cloud import storage
import requests

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket("bucket")
blob = bucket.blob("imageaddress.dcm")
dicom = blob.download_as_bytes()
print(len(dicom))


response=requests.post(url='the url', data = dicom,headers={"Accept":"application/octet-stream"})

print(response.text)
```

The problem is that in nodejs I get this error:"Error "error during parsing dicomParser.ByteStream: parameter byteArray is not of type Uint8Array or Buffer"

I tried the same request in postman and it goes through successfully. I am not sure if python bytes and javascript uint8array are the same format or there has to be some kind of type conversion? I have tried both requests and urllib3 libraries and getting the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Try **headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}** 2) Verify which POST data format (content-type) the other side expects. 3) I prefer to break the problem in two. Debug uploading a local file: **curl -d @imageaddress.dcm -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -X POST**

Comment: thank you so much headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} actually worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding

```
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
```

as John Hanley said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452276/download-image-from-google-cloud-storage-and-send-it-in-a-request-fails/71463766#comment126293937_71452276) solved the problem.